# Sorting numbers of 10**6 digits in Python 2 efficiently

Tags: python, performance, python-2.7, long-integer

I used the `long` type to store numbers and sort using normal sort method, but it was not efficient enough.

I think `long(raw_input())` takes too much time.

Can someone think of an efficient way to solve it?

```
n = int(raw_input().strip())
unsorted = []
for i in xrange(n):
    term = long(raw_input())
    unsorted.append(term)

for i in sorted(unsorted):
    print i
```

Comment: How many million-digit numbers do you have?

Comment: 2*(10**5) is the number of numbers that I need to sort.

Comment: Well, that should be over in an eyeblink, if you have enough memory. I would /guess/ most of the time you experience is spent in file i/o. Please do post code (and a link to your data file, if any) that readers can just copy and paste to reproduce the problem.

Comment: This sounds like *at least* 180 GB of data you're loading/having to store in memory (with 0 overhead).

Comment: Here's one suggestion: do an external merge-sort.

Comment: Well i/o isn't the headache, as it is a competitive programming problem,and have a look at the code above

Comment: Where are you stuck? You said you guess that `long(raw_input())` is the bottleneck, so the next step would be to prove or disprove that.

Comment: how will an external merge-sort benefit ? @Cheersandhth.-Alf

Comment: Are the number ranges clamped?  (e.g. 1...1000000) and can you have duplicates ( and do those get printed too?)?

Comment: @PaulHankin Yes, as I am assuming in-built sort method of python is efficient enough. so the only time costly operation seems to be `long(raw_input())` is there any other way to take input of such big size?
@selbie the only limitation to numbers is that it is of 10**6 length.

Comment: Let the number remain a string itself and compare them using string comparisons

Comment: What are your memory/time limits? Do you have access to a filesystem?

Comment: @AbhishekJebaraj: An external merge sort can help when your machine doesn't have the requisite amount of RAM. Otherwise it will be trashing. There are more advanced ways to do an external sort, but merge-sort is doable and simple.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Absolutely but he mentioned in the comments its for competitive programming and there they do not have very high memory intensive problems and thus it would work.

Comment: @AbhishekJebaraj: Eh? It’s mentioned in a comment that there are 200,000 of these 1,000,000-digit numbers to sort.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Yes but competitve coding is also mentioned.. There they usually have a cap.. so if they say 2*10^5 means you can't use some simple bubble sort as they'll give many small integers in a test case and big integers in some other test case

Comment: @AbhishekJebaraj: "you can't use some simple bubble sort", (1) nobody's mentioned bubble sort so far, and (2) no programming language provides a bubble sort routine, it's that useless.

Comment: As you noted sorting `31415, 1, 3, 10` as strings isn't same as numbers, but what if you sort them as list of `(len(string), string)` tuples instead? Also, `unsorted.sort()` could save a whole lot of memory and probably speed as well compared to `sorted()`

Comment: +1 @TommiKomulainen for pointing it out. (y) will try out, but acc to me it won't make significant change in speed.

Answer (score 1):

Since you said it is a competitive programming question this solution would work otherwise it would never work as it needs way too much of memory and would break in the bad cases. But in competitive programming the constraints are not so much and it should work.

We merely add comparators ie the **gt** and **lt** methods which decide the comparison between 2 objects.

```
class VeryBigNumber(object):
    def __init__(self,number_string):
        self.number = number_string


def __gt__(self,other):
    if len(self.number)>len(other.number):
        return True
    elif len(self.number)<len(other.number):
        return False

    for i in xrange(min(len(self.number),len(other.number))):
        if int(self.number[i])>int(other.number[i]):
            return True
        elif int(self.number[i])<int(other.number[i]):
            return False
    return False

def __eq__(self,other):
    return self.number == other.number

def __lt__(self,other):
    return not (self.__eq__(other) or self.__gt__(other))

arr = []
for i in xrange(n):
    arr.append(VeryBigNumber(raw_input().strip())

arr = sorted(arr)
for a in arr:
    print a.number,
```

Big Explanation:

1. In the comments you had said it's for a coding competition. This assures us that the memory if small enough for us to be able to read in under a second.
2. We don't convert such a big string to a number as that would be unnecessary. Instead we keep the string as is.
3. How do we sort it then? We make our own class and use string comparisons.
4. These work by comparing the character digits between strings and thus only one character is converted to int at a time which is very efficient.
5. I've tested the above code and it works correctly

Comment: There is difference between string sorting and number sorting.
Lets say am sorting 31415, 1, 3, 10
In string, It will be sorted as: 1,10,3,31415 (as per ASCII)
whereas, It should be 1,3,10,31415

Comment: @AbhishekKhandelwal: If all your numbers have the same number of digits, it’s the same.

Comment: @AbhishekKhandelwal Yea! And that's why I've added my own comparators!.. I'm not using standard string comparisons. But this also assumes there are no unnecessary zeroes at start

Comment: @AbhishekJebaraj, but inside your comparators you are converting them to integers anyway, so would it make any difference ?

Comment: @AbhishekKhandelwal I'm converting each character to an integer, making the comparison and moving on.

Comment: @AbhishekKhandelwal Sorry there was a mistake in the previous code /\ have fixed it in the latest edit

Comment: @AbhishekJebaraj appreciate your code. But it take 0.2 sec to solve a particular input sets which was solved in 0.1 sec by the code given in question.
As said by Tommi Komulainen sort() would be more efficient than sorted but still the execution time was 0.2 secs